I keep getting these errors "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179 , "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10881 , Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 57644)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ((os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')), )


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'files')

STATIC FILES_FINDERS = [
> >     "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
> >     "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
> > ]

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('paintings/', views.paintings, name='paintings'),
path('sculptures/', views.sculptures, name='sculptures'),
path('engravings/', views.engravings, name='engravings'),
path('future_auction/', views.future_auction, name='future_auction'),
path('winners/', views.winners, name='winners'),
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


I was trying to deploy my project but when i turned DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] and run the server,i got these issues

which server do you use to host your static files in production? AWS B3? Nginx? Apache?  Whitenoise? So please which one? If none, I would like to know, so that we can help you out.

AWS E2 With nginx

I believe the error you are having is due to the configuration of the static files on AWS E2 with Nginx. Ensure that the files point to the right location and that everything is well configured. We would like to see your Nginx configuration path, and AWS E2 instance, pls hide your keys, don't show them to us here, or to anyone.

Run this command on your terminal to see where Django is supposed to locate your static files - it is a good debugging tool I often use; it might be of help to you. python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 css/styles.css

Found 'style.css' here:
C:\Users\chinm\PycharmProjects\ArtAuctionProject\Art\static\style.css
C:\Users\chinm\PycharmProjects\ArtAuctionProject\Art\static\style.css
Looking in the following locations:
C:\Users\chinm\PycharmProjects\ArtAuctionProject\Art\static
